# Python GEKKO: How to express contraints with random variables in gekko?

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I spent a time trying to solve the following problem with gekko, but hard to tell if I am writting the codes right. I am saying this, because the problem become infeasible when I decrease a bit the value of tau (which is not the case theoritically). I need your assistance;

[image: Optimization problem]

It is a tracking problem, with state variables depending on multiple values xi.

Here is my codes;

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Time points
n = 10
m.time = np.linspace(0, 10, n)

# parameters
alpha = 0.95
m1 = 0.5
m2 = 0.3
tau = 0.5

# Number of random samples
N = 10

# create the samples
Xi = np.random.rand(N,n)
S = []
for i in range(N):
  S.append(m.Param(list(Xi[i])))

# State variables
x = m.Array(m.Var, N, value=5.0)

# Control variable
u = m.Var()

# reference trajectory
x_val = [5.0, 2.31, 1.45, 1.01, 0.75, 0.57, 0.45, 0.36, 0.31, 0.28]
x_r = m.Param(x_val)

# Equation
m.Equations(5 * x[i].dt() == -x[i]**2 + u + S[i] for i in range(N)) 

m.Equation((1/N)*m.sum([(1 + m1 * tau) / (1 + m2 * tau * m.exp((-(x[i] - x_r[i])**2 + 10) / tau)) for i in range(N)]) <= 1 - alpha)

m.Obj((1/N)*(m.sum([(x[i] - x_r[i])**2 for i in range(N)])) + u**2)

# Solve the differential equation
m.options.IMODE = 6  #
m.options.SOLVER = 3; # 1: APOPT, 2:BPOPT, 3:IPOPT
m.options.MAX_ITER = 10000 # change maximum iterations
m.solve(disp=True)
```

I expected a decreasing objective value as tau decreases.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a difference with the equation in the image and the one that is written in the model.

```py
m.Equation((1/N)*m.sum([(1 + m1 * tau) / 
           (1 + m2 * tau * m.exp((-(x[i] - x_r[i])**2 + 10) /
           tau)) for i in range(N)]) <= 1 - alpha)
```

An additional `/tau` is in the denominator and the signs should be `(xi-xd)^2-10`.

One other potential issue for convergence is divide-by-zero. One way to improve convergence is to constrain the denominator to be greater than a small value such as `1e-3`.

```py
den = m.Array(m.Var,N,lb=1e-3)
m.Equations([den[i]==1+m2*tau*m.exp(((x[i]-x_r[i])**2-10)) for i in range(N)])
m.Equation((1/N)*m.sum([(1 + m1 * tau) / den[i] for i in range(N)]) <= 1 - alpha)
```

The infeasibility is likely from the inequality constraint. Try relaxing the inequality constraint with `p-alpha` and with a larger `p` value until the problem becomes feasible. In this case, a successful solution is found when `p=5`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

# Time points
n = 10
m.time = np.linspace(0, 10, n)

# parameters
alpha = 0.95
m1 = 0.5
m2 = 0.3
tau = 0.5
p = 5.0

# Number of random samples
N = 10

# create the samples
Xi = np.random.rand(N,n)
S = []
for i in range(N):
  S.append(m.Param(list(Xi[i])))

# State variables
x = m.Array(m.Var, N, value=5.0)

# Control variable
u = m.Var()

# reference trajectory
x_val = [5.0, 2.31, 1.45, 1.01, 0.75, 0.57, 0.45, 0.36, 0.31, 0.28]
x_r = m.Param(x_val)

# Equation
m.Equations(5 * x[i].dt() == -x[i]**2 + u + S[i] for i in range(N))

den = m.Array(m.Var,N,lb=1e-3)
m.Equations([den[i]==1+m2*tau*m.exp(((x[i]-x_r[i])**2-10)) for i in range(N)])
m.Equation((1/N)*m.sum([(1 + m1 * tau) / den[i] for i in range(N)]) <= p - alpha)

m.Obj((1/N)*(m.sum([(x[i] - x_r[i])**2 for i in range(N)])) + u**2)

# Solve the differential equation
m.options.IMODE = 6  #
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # 1: APOPT, 2:BPOPT, 3:IPOPT
m.options.MAX_ITER = 200 # change maximum iterations
m.solve(disp=True)
```